# Follow up on a previous question of mine (characters in star algebra)

Tags: functional-analysis, proof-verification, c-star-algebras

It is a fact that the character space of a commutative $C^\ast$-algebra is non-empty. Consider the following proof, also included [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/855234/another-question-about-c-ast-algebra):

Proof:

[image]

My question is: could someone please explain to me why the latter part involving the unitisation and the restrtiction of the character to $A$ is necessary?

Concretely, my own proof would be the following and I don't know why it might not be correct:

Recall that in a commutative non-unital Banach algebra $A$ we have $\sigma (a) = \{ \tau (a) \mid \tau \in \Omega (A) \} \cup \{0\}$. Since there exists $\tau $ such that $|\tau (a) | = \|a\| > 0$ it follows immediately that $\tau \in \Omega (A)$ is a non-zero character which proves the claim.

Comment: I'm not so sure about your characterization for the spectrum. How do you define $\sigma(a)$ for a non-unital algebra? Note that Martini's argument in the other question uses that the algebra is unital.

Comment: @MartinArgerami Thank you for your comment. For non-unital algebra it is defined as the spectrum in the unitisation $\widetilde{A}$. Yes martini's argument uses that $A$ is unital. But doesn't the proof I give above work in a non-unital setting? And if it does, why the complicated argument in the book?

Answer (score 1):

The unitisation is necessary to show the existence of characters: you need the existence of maximal ideals, which you can only assure they exist in unital abelian algebras.

I don't know where the problem is; I have to admit I know nothing about Banach algebra unitisations. Consider this example: let $A=\ell^1(\mathbb N)$, with the pointwise addition and multiplication. It is not hard to see that the characters are precisely the maps 
$$
a\longmapsto a(n)
$$
for a fixed $n$. But then if for example you consider the sequence $(2^{-n})$, then $|\tau(a)|\leq1/2$ for all characters, while $\|a\|_1=1$. So it looks like there is no character with $|\tau(a)|=\|a\|$.

Comment: Dear Martin, thank you very much for your answer. I think your example does not apply in this case because $\ell^1$ is not a $C^\ast$-algebra. To see this, consider the element $a=(i,-i,0,0,0, \dots )$. Then $\|a^\ast a \|\neq \|a\|^2$. $$ \\$$ I spent much time comparing my own proof to the proof in the question above and I still don't understand what I am missing. Should anything come to your mind about this later can you please add it to the answer?

Comment: Of course it is not a C$^*$-algebra. The result is true in C$^*$-algebras, how could there be a counterexample? I'm addressing your question where you are considering a non-unital Banach algebra; you said that in such an algebra $\sigma (a) = \{ \tau (a) \mid \tau \in \Omega (A) \} \cup \{0\}$, which is what I wrote a counterexample to.

Comment: Please could you enlighten me as  to what's going on here? It's a theorem in Murphy's book (see thm. 1.3.4. on page 14) that in a non-unital abelian Banach algebra $A$ we have $\sigma (a) = \{\tau (a) \mid \tau \in \Omega (A)\} \cup \{0\}$, so surely there cannot be a counterexample. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Also every proper modular ideal is contained in a maximal ideal so even if there is no $1$ it seems plausible that maximal ideals exist. (?)

Comment: I stand corrected on my comment, but I think my answer stays on. What Murphy says is correct. What is wrong is your extrapolation that $\|a\|\in\sigma(a)$ or, more generally, that $\|a\|$ agrees with the spectral radius. This holds for selfadjoints in a C$*^$ (and Murphy uses that in the paragraph you copied in the question) but doesn't for most non-normals, and usually fails in arbitrary Banach algebras.

Comment: @MartinArgerami True but I still don't understand what's going on here. Concretely, what is OP doing wrong in the proof in the question? In the question the C star algebra is not zero so you can pick any non-zero element $a$ and use that $r(a^\ast a) = \|a^\ast a\|>0$, no?

Comment: The OP is asking two things. First one is why going to the unitization is required;  that is answered by looking at the proof of 1.3.4. Second one is about using the argument on a Banach algebra; in that case you don't have the C $^*$-identity, and that's what my answer points out.